# How to print in UEFI WITHOUT usage of UEFI.h or any other library

Tags: uefi

I want to learn how printing works in UEFI but can't find any reliable resource that details the function. I don't want to copy from the library as that won't tell me much of how it actually works.

Can anyone please explain how printing in UEFI works?
Thank you

Comment: Have you read the UEFI spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, this is impossible, because the printing behavior does not print anywhere really, you can see it on UEFI Shell which is an UEFI App by itself.
If you want to implement low level printing, you can read about using serial ports, this is the easiest one.